# Iterate columns on Groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I created a 6 column DataFrame to make a real-state analysis. The columns are the following: index, rent price, borough, nº of bedrooms, parking spaces and floor area. Afterwards I create a groupby object:

```
boroughs = df.groupby(by = "Borough")
```

As expected, now it has the borough as index, and another 4 columns. I'd like to know how could I iterate over these columns (maybe using a `for` loop). My end goal is to generalize the following outliers-deletion expression for every column:

```
Q1 = boroughs.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = boroughs.quantile(0.75)
IIQ = Q3 - Q1
inf_lim = Q1 - 1.5*IIQ
sup_lim = Q3 + 1.5*IIQ

rent = pd.DataFrame()
for borough in boroughs.groups.keys():
    which_borough = df["Borough"] == borough
    not_outlier = ((df["Rent_Price"] >= inf_lim[borough]) & (df["Rent_Price"] <= sup_lim[borough]))
    selection = which_borough & not_outlier
    df_selection = df[selection]
    aluguel = pd.concat([rent, df_selection])
```

`df["Rent_Price"].describe()` info:

```
count        757.000000
mean        3943.546896
std        45374.384250
min            0.000000
25%          750.000000
50%         1200.000000
75%         1850.000000
max      1000000.000000
```

`rent["Rent_Price"].describe()` info:

```
count      701.000000
mean      1478.723252
std       1651.573796
min          0.000000
25%        750.000000
50%       1200.000000
75%       1800.000000
max      35999.000000
```

As you can see, after the process, mean, std and max are significantly lower, and it was removed 56 items.

Comment: please, show an sample exemple of input df and expected output df

Comment: @BenoitDrogou I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, but I've made some alteration

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for col in ['Rent_Price', 'borough', 'number_of_bedrooms', 'parking_spaces', 'floor_area']:
    ans=df[(df[col]<=(df[col].quantile(0.75)+(1.5*(df[col].quantile(0.75)-df[col].quantile(0.25))))) & (df[col]>=(df[col].quantile(0.25)-(1.5*(df[col].quantile(0.75)-df[col].quantile(0.25)))))][col].describe()
    print(f'{col} Summary')
    print(ans)
```

---

By Borough:

```
for b in set(df.borough):
    df1=df[df.borough==b]
    for col in ['rent price', 'borough', 'nº of bedrooms', 'parking spaces', 'floor area']:
        ans=df1[(df1[col]<=(df1[col].quantile(0.75)+(1.5*(df1[col].quantile(0.75)-df1[col].quantile(0.25))))) & (df1[col]>=(df1[col].quantile(0.25)-(1.5*(df1[col].quantile(0.75)-df1[col].quantile(0.25)))))][col].describe()
        print(f'{col} Summary')
        print(ans)
```